# Will background modes in iOS allows to run the respective mode options for infinite time?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If my app is in the background, I need to track whether the user is in online and update the online timestamp in my local DB.

I tried to implement this by using the background fetch mode using a timer that fires the track function every 5 sec when the app is in the background. Whenever the app comes in the foreground I will end the background task and invalidate the timer.

But while testing I was not able to continue this task after 3 min in the background in iOS7.0. It was automatically stopped after 3 min. Is this a problem with ios7.0 alone?

My code implementation is given below:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0 target: self
                                                selector: @selector(callAfterFiveSec:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

    self.bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@" Online timestamp check in background:" expirationHandler:^{
    }];

}

- (void)callAfterFiveSec:(NSTimer *)t
{

    // Save timestamp to DB
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    [self.timer invalidate];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
    self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Is there any way to continue this task infinity, until the user forcefully close the app in background?

I have seen so many posts telling like, we need to finish the background task at some point of time and some implemented the same by playing soundless music which will make the app running if the device gets locked too.

Similarly, Is the location update background mode runs for an infinite time if the app is in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Background fetch is not a continuous background mode (like audio playback or location updates).
Enabling this feature will make iOS trigger your AppDelegate's `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler;` method.
It's made to download ressources. [See this.](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/)

While you can set how often you would like to see iOS to trigger this method, you can't force it to do it. iOS will decide when to call it and can even stop if it needs to (like low battery...)

---

Now if you need to ping your server every X seconds in the background, your app will need a feature that requires a continuous background mode like an audio player, GPS updates or a Bluetooth accessory.
If you try to trick Apple with an unused background mode, you will get caught during review and your app will be rejected. They actually ask "how are you using X background mode ?"

---

Also, I'm not sure why you need a timestamp to be saved every 5 seconds even if the app is in the background but if you do it the device's battery will not make it through the day.
Each network call wakes the radio up and drains the battery.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Quentin. I gave 5 sec as an example. The thing is, I need to track if a user is in online or offline every XXXX seconds, even my app is in the background for an infinite time and I was not able to achieve that.

Comment: See the second part of my answer. This is the only way. But if your app doesn't have a genuine feature that use those modes, you will get caught.

Comment: Also, are we able to get the continuous location updates, if the app is  closed by the user (and not in background)?

Comment: No. As soon as the app is terminated by the user (from the app switch screen), ALL activities related to this app are killed: location updates, background fetch...

Comment: okay....Then in case of the skype app....We will be able to get calls though we terminate the app..It's also using VOIP. Then how is this happen?I know Push notifications will be used....But what about the calls we receive?

Comment: When you receive a skype call, you actually just receive a push notification. And when you open the app you can then answer. But the app didn't get any information before you opened it.

Comment: Okay.But I am confused with apple documentation on 'Location updates'. "You enable location support from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. Enabling this mode does not prevent the system from suspending the app, but it does tell the system that it should wake up the app whenever there is new location data to deliver. Thus, this key effectively lets the app run in the background to process location updates whenever they occur."...So Is it saying like though we terminate the app, it will awake the app whenever a new location data is received?

Comment: No. If the app is terminated by the user. NOTHING will wake up your app until the user manually restarts it.

Comment: Then what is the apple talking about? Sorry, I am not able to understand it completely...

Comment: Locations update will wake up your app if it has been suspended naturally. By the system, not by the user from the app switch screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92729/discussion-between-jamesdon-and-quentin-hayot).